# Chef update config file

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef cookbook which installs nginx and install a custom nginx.conf file. It's basically the same cookbook on Opscode, and uses cookbook_file to install the file.

If I make a change to the conf file, then rerun the cookbook using chef the configuration file isn't updated.  This seems like a bug -- am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using `chef-client` or `chef-solo`? If `chef-client`, Have you uploaded the new cookbook to the chef server with `knife cookbook upload` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In chef that the order of commands in the recipe is the order of execution. if you kept the `template` for the `nginx.conf` and it comes after your `cookbook_file` command, the generated template will overwrite your file.

e.g.

```
# cookbook file
cookbook_file "#{node[:nginx][:dir]}/nginx.conf" do
  source "my_nginx.conf"
  mode 0644
  owner "root"
  group "root"
end

# template
template "nginx.conf" do
  path "#{node[:nginx][:dir]}/nginx.conf"
  source "nginx.conf.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0644
  notifies :reload, "service[nginx]"
end
```

The `template` would overwrite the file laid down by `cookbook_file`.

Comment: This answer is spot-on and perfect.

Answer (score 1):

In testing I have found that if you have `:create_if_missing` set it will not updated the file if it the contents have changed.  Set `:create` and it will.